# Shape of Data with Itemized Changes

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-munging

What is the best shape of data below for tidy analysis?

For a given account, data provides:

- Account name
- Amount Requested
- Itemized Changes [bracketed]; Total Changes (no brackets)
- Final amount provided

A total of $100 was requested for Account1. Appropriators added [$10] to the amount for a "grade increase," but decreased it by [-$20] due to foreign currency fluctuations. The total changed amount was -$10. The total amount provided was $90.

How can I tidy this data in a way that preserves the itemized explanations but also allows for grouping, mutating, etc.

````
library(tidyverse)

tibble(account = c("Account.1", "Account.1", "Account.1"),
       requested = c(100, NA, NA),
       changed  = c("-10", "[10]", "[-20]"),
       explanation = c(NA, "grade increase", "foreign currency adjustment"),
       provided = c(90, NA, NA) )

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   account   requested changed explanation                 provided
#>   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>   <chr>                          <dbl>
#> 1 Account.1       100 -10     <NA>                              90
#> 2 Account.1        NA [10]    grade increase                    NA
#> 3 Account.1        NA [-20]   foreign currency adjustment       NA
```
````

Created on 2018-06-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow for referential integrity, i'd actually drop a lot of info and separate this out into 2 tables:

```
totals <- dat[!is.na(dat$requested), -c(3,4,5)]
changes <- dat[is.na(dat$requested), c(1,3,4)]
changes$changed <- as.numeric(gsub("[][]","", changes$changed))

totals

#    account requested
#1 Account.1       100

changes

#    account changed                 explanation
#2 Account.1      10              grade increase
#3 Account.1     -20 foreign currency adjustment
```

That way you can calculate the `totals$changed` and `totals$provided` columns by `sum`-ming the `changes$changed` column and subtracting from `totals$requested`, with no risk of creating any conflicting data.
There are also no `NA` values in any column now.
The mix of numeric/character data in the original `changed` column has also been removed.